# Creating a multi-chat client

Tags: android, xmpp, instantmessenger

How do I create a  XMPP chat client in Android for Yahoo, Gmail, AOL, etc., How do Nimbizz, eBuddy, Fring do it?

Comment: May I know why this post was down voted?

Comment: can you provide SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT, SERVICE_NAME for Aol and MSN Xmpp client's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Smack API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/). It provides all you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Think Smack can be used only with XMPP servers. It doesn't support OSCAR or other communication protocols?

Comment: @Ragunath: I dont know that much details. But tried it to connect to Gmail, Yahoo and MSN. It worked successfully.

Comment: That's great. Could you please give the Yahoo and MSN servers with port?

Comment: @Ragunath: Use Registration class of Smack API to register in yahoo and msn. As gateway string give yahoo.server and msn.server where "server" is your XMPP server.

Comment: Thank you Harry, can I get back to you in case of queries?

Comment: @Ragunath: you are always welcome.

Comment: @HarryJoy can you provide server_host and port_number for AIM, MSN and yahoo i tried this xmpp.messenger.live.com for msn with out fair. can you provide more details on this..

Comment: @RajaReddyP for msn: `messenger.hotmail.com` and for yahoo: `scs.msg.yahoo.com`. Don't know about AIM.

Comment: what about the post numbers, is it common for all client present ia m using 5222 and smack library. is it suitable for all...

Comment: port for msn: 1863 and yahoo: 5050.

Comment: thanks Harry Joy, can i get back to you if i stuck at any case..

Comment: @RajaReddyP sure. If I have time and know the answer will try to help you.

Comment: i am getting this warning No response from the server.,at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:73)

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement every single protocol your IM platforms use:

1. GTALK (XMPP)
2. Yahoo (proprietary protocol)
3. AOL (Oscar)

So on, so forth.

Alternatively, you can have a SINGLE PROTOCOL on your Android device and use a PROXY IM SERVER to connect to all accounts (I think this is the way FRING and EBUDDY do it, not sure though).

Comment: Are there any providers who offer proxies for the purpose?

Comment: @Ragunath Jawahar: good question. I have no idea. Check out http://www.igniterealtime.org/

Comment: @Ragunath Jawahar: all that I know of are only doing this for their own app.

Answer (score 3):

The [Pidgin IM client](http://www.pidgin.im) has its own [libpurple](http://www.pidgin.im/~elb/blog/architecture.html), which implements pretty much all of the major IM protocols. There's some details and dogs on their site about the architecture.

But, basically, unless the IM network has published the specs on their protocol, most multi-network clients have to do reverse engineering (and/or just grab details from something like libpurple) to do their own implementations.

Comment: libpurple is a C library are there any ports for Java?

Comment: maybe libpurple could be compiled natively with the Android NDK ?